# Dynamic creation of models in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dynamic

as you know Spring MVC allow you to access a db table through a Model which is defined in a .java and known to Spring at time of compilation. In my case these are specified inside:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <value>.......model.Name1</value>
            <value>.......model.Name2</value>

</list>
    </property>
```

.......
The problem is that I need to create some tables at time of execution, so I need to create dynamically a model for each of them.
Is it possible and how?
Thanks in advance,
Francesco

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Could explain in more detail what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Hibernate in Spring MVC ; For example

1. Hibernate Example Src/main/resources example:

   ```
   <class name="YOUR CLASS NAME IN JAVA" table="TM_ANDROID_CATEGORIES">

       <id name="_id" column="category_no" type="long">
           <generator class="sequence">
               <param name="sequence">SEQUENCE NAME</param> 
           </generator>
       </id>

       <property name="_dirName" not-null="true">
          <column name="category_path_name" />
       </property>

       <property name="_nameTR" not-null="true">
          <column name="category_name" />
       </property>

       <property name="_nameEN" not-null="true">
          <column name="category_name_en" />
       </property>

       <property name="_typeNo" not-null="true">
          <column name="category_type" />
       </property>

       <property name="_isAdult" not-null="true">
          <column name="category_adult" />
       </property>                          
   </class>
   ```
2. Java Class. You have to make java class like hibernate.xml in src/main/java
3. Make bean for hibernate in root-context.xml Example:

   ```
   <bean id="_hibernateSessionFactory"
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

   <property name="dataSource">
       <ref bean="_dataSourceProxy"></ref>
   </property>

   <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
           <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">false</prop>
           <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
           <prop key="connection.useUnicode">true</prop>   
           <prop key="connection.characterEncoding">utf-8</prop>


           <prop key="hibernate.connection.defaultNChar">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

       </props>
   </property>

   <property name="mappingResources">
       <list>
           <value>hibernate/content/AndroidCategory.hbm.xml</value>
       </list>
   </property>
   ```
4. Make autowired this hibernate and java classes

For more info:

[CLICK HERE](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/)

Comment: It is not very clear. Could you please post a small full example?

Comment: You can find everything here : http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

JDBC provides all you need to create tables and dynamically queries of modifies them. But ORM maps tables to java classes that must be compiled before being used.

Spring has excellent support for JDBC, just Read The Famous Manual (Spring Reference Manual of course). If you give an example of what you want to do I could give you more details.